# Need help in jquery.post() to fullcontact api

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcontact

Can anybody help me how to invoke the post method provided here. I am unable to do so using the apigee console and even with jquery!

http://fullcontact.com/docs/documentation/#vcard

the call to this post method will be done using jquery.post(), any code snippets on the same will be very helpful!

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [FullContact jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/fullcontact/fullcontact-api-jquery-plugin)

```
    var vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0\nEMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:lorangb@gmail.com\nEND:VCARD";
    $.fullcontact.enrichVCard('YOUR API KEY',vcard,function(enrichedVCard){
           console.log(enrichedVCard);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$.post({
    url: "https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.vcf",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
             apiKey: "50211c64734215gh",
             vcard: {
                VERSION: "3.0",
            N: "Lorang;Bart",
            FN: "Bart Lorang",
            ORG: "FullContact",
            TITLE: "Co-Founder & CEO"
                ....
                ...
             }
     }  
});
```

Comment: any idea how to create the vcard data for sending??

Comment: tried but didnt got any response from the server. another thing how to include this "TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:(303) 736-9406"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var vcardString = 'your vcard string here';

$.post({
    url: "https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.vcf",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
             apiKey: "YOUR KEY HERE",
             vcard: vcardString
    }
});
```

The response will contain the raw vCard text.

Comment: this gives error as forbiden as apikey is not included here. I already posted my code in http://getsatisfaction.com/